# Android: need uninstall because of existent package even it have not been installed before

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am running into this problem after I click on run to run an application for testing in my phone. Actually this problem require to uninstall the existed application but I have never installed it one time.

Thank you for your help!

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFUeP.png

Comment: did you updated android your android studio recently ?

Comment: what happens when you click ok?

Comment: Which device are you using to test your application? If it's Xiaomi, then disable Instant Run. Go to: File> Settings> Build, Execution, Deployment> Instant Run> Uncheck first option> Click Apply and Ok.

Comment: Yes, I did. I am in use of Android 2.3.1.
When I click ok it did nothing with error message (Session 'app': Error installing APKs).

Failed to finalize session : Unknown failure (Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires android.permission.ASEC_CREATE permission)

My device is Azus Zenfone 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you updated android studio recently remember to change gradle build tools to 2.3.0 inside top level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

and you should also make sure you use BuildToolsVersion 25

```
    android {
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

}
```

IF THAT DOESN'T WORK-----

***Try turning off instant run***

**Mac**
Android Studio > Preferences > Build, execution, deploy > Instant Run.

**Windows**
File > Setting

Comment: It still didn't work with error message (Session 'app': Error installing APKs). Failed to finalize session : Unknown failure (Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires android.permission.ASEC_CREATE permission).

Comment: what version did you have and when did you update it, when did to problem start to occur?

Comment: I am currently use Android version 2.3.1. I have updated it around 2 weeks ago. I saw the problem after debug key error and generated new one.

Comment: The main error is about (Session 'app': Error installing APKs).

Comment: ok try turning of instant run Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, execution, deploy -> Instant Run.

Comment: I can't find Preferences.

Comment: Go to the help tab and search preferences.

Comment: It is about the Instant Run. Thank you very much! Android Studio > Preferences is only in Mac but in window is File > Setting.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept my answer as the correct answer.

Comment: @SarithNob so you are not going to except it as the correct answer after I helped you to fix it?

Comment: There will be a check mark next to my answer. It will turn green

Comment: How have to click on the check mark, please look at the image in this link ---   https://ibb.co/e3BFLk

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project and run again.

Comment: And this is the most generic solution ever!

Answer (score 0):

In Your Mobile go to the developer option and MAke sure that your usb debugging option is on

if you are using xiomi mobile there is one option below allow via usb  make sure it is on .

if you dont know how to see developer option in mobile please google it its very easy

if none of this thing will work then click on the file in android studio then settings . then expand the Build Execution And Deployment option .click on the instant run option and then disable it  .hope this might work

Comment: Oh, I don't mean it. I have tested many apps but after I upgrade Android Studio to 2.3.0 and 2.3.1 it bring up this issue along the time with my app out of date of debug key.

Comment: After that every new app created can't be installed in my phone at all. I use Asus Zenfone 6.

Comment: i ran through same problem so i off my instant run setting in my settings. i hope i will help you